# Cakephp picture upload does not update right away

Tags: caching, cakephp, upload, image

When I upload a picture into my website and redirect back to the page, the picture does not update until you refresh the page a few times. I assume the browser is showing the previous cached image. Is there a simple way in cakephp to prevent this? the form code is below:

```
    echo $form->create('UserImage', array('controller' => 'user_images', 'action' => 'add', 'type' => 'file'));
    echo $form->file('File');
    echo $form->submit('Upload');
    echo $form->end();
```

Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: The issue may be with how you are 'redirecting'... can you show your code related to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the image with same name than older one, browser will keep that image in cache. Like Anh Pham said, append timestamp or whatever random string to image name and it should load the new image. But, I would rather recommend **save** the image with different name, **not just print it in view with some random string**, so browser can load it from cache after first pageload.

Answer (score 2):

put a timestamp in your image url to force a refresh:

> ```
> echo $html->image('image.jpg?'.time()));
> ```